# jQuery Lint Errors

Tags: jquery, jquery-lint

I found out about jQuery Lint in the Firebug plugin. However its results are confusing and very hard to try and satisfy. I get hundreds of errors saying `jQuery (...) called incorrectly`.

For example this line comes up with that warning. What am i doing wrong here?

```
$('#myTextBox').val(someValue);
```

And when i try to remove all the rows from a tbody that has no rows it throws an error that stops all javascript on the page. It says no elements were found with that selector and then that remove is not a function.

```
$('#myTbody > tr').remove();
```

Do i really have to add extra code to work around this? How is jQuery Lint meant to be helpful?

Comment: r u using  other JS library too??? like `mootools`, `Dojo` or `prototype`

Comment: [JS/JS-related thing] Lint is never meant to be helpful.

Comment: @diEcho - No other libraries. @BoltClock - Then whats the point of it?

Comment: paste your code here or on jsfiddle.net

Comment: @diEcho - There is 1500 lines of javascript for this page. I gave a couple of examples in the question. I just want to know whats wrong with the first example. I can work out the other stuff from there.

Comment: for `val(somevalue)`  :> is that `somevalue` is JavaScript variable or a string?? if string then use `'` around that

Comment: its a variable. and doing .toString() after the variable doesn't help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I made a simple example: [**jsfiddle.net/DJzFe/**](http://jsfiddle.net/DJzFe/)

There you will see that your 2 lines of code does not warn on jQuery Lint if you use **jQuery 1.4.4,** but I suspect that you are using **jQuery 1.5.1 which hasn't been tested by jQuery Lint yet** ([it has been tested only with 1.3.2 and 1.4.4](https://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Lint/blob/master/README.md)). And in 1.5.1 that statements will warn as you described: `jQuery(...) called incorrectly`